# C++ - Linking to glog for cross-compiled windows executable fails

Tags: windows, cross-compiling, glog

I'm trying to compile my code to dll format (instead of .so format) and I'm doing it on my Ubuntu machine with a MinGW compiler (which was compiled from [mxe](https://mxe.cc/#download)).

The code uses Google's glog library for logging, and is compiled via Makefile (no cmake usage). The code compiles well for Linux, but when I switch the g++ used in the Makefile to the i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ compiled from mxe, the linker shows many errors such as this -

```
undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int)'
undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
```

To publish this question I've recreated the issue on a small (non-dll) executable -

```c
#define GOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL
#include "glog/logging.h"

int main() {
    LOG(ERROR) << "HELLO";
    return 0;
}
```

with the following compilation line -

```
i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -L/path/to/library/directory -I/path/to/include/dir \
    -static-libstdc++ simple_main.cpp -lglog -o simple_main.exe
```

And I've put the glog include files in the include directory and the libglog.a in the directory given with `-L`. When doing this I'm getting the same errors as my real library -

```
/tmp/ccBBAXeQ.o:simple_main.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int)'
/tmp/ccBBAXeQ.o:simple_main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
/tmp/ccBBAXeQ.o:simple_main.cpp:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
/tmp/ccBBAXeQ.o:simple_main.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's worth mentioning that my issue is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866294/trying-to-use-glog-on-windows-results-undefined-references) issue, and I've tried using CMake on my simple main to recreate the issue, but the answer supplied there didn't work for me (still getting the same errors).

I also made sure that the `libglog.a` file indeed contains the undefined symbols (via `nm libglog.a | c++filt | grep ~LogMessage`), and I also tried linking against a windows-built `glog.lib` which I compiled on windows, and this also didn't seem to work (the linker failed to identify the .lib file).

Thus, I'm not sure what the problem is, and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Any reason you are avoiding ETW?

Comment: @IInspectable Because my library was (originally) a linux library (and I still need it to compile for linux as well as windows), and thus I need a logging mechanism which is cross platform. Also, I want to avoid replacing all of my logging usage in the existing code and stay with glog.